# Remove javascript property from Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Hi I want to remove sticky property from reviewButtonVm.positionStaticStyle class in Android Webview.

Below is the javascript code for this

```
<button>
 <div ng-class="hashButtonVm.positionStaticStyle" class="sticky">
</button>
```

I tried below webview code

```
@Override 
public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    view.loadUrl("javascript:$('.hashButtonVm').removeClass('sticky');");
}
```

but somehow its not working.

Comment: did you try the code on a regular browser? it doesn't seem to work for me on jsfiddle

Comment: This property needs to be removed from Android code

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your onPageFinished method

```
 "$('button .sticky').removeClass('sticky');"
```

Its working for me.